# TIMESTAMP column issue CDH5 vs CDH6 in parquet table

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hive, impala

We recently upgraded our server from CDH 5 to CDH 6 . When inserting data to TIMESTAMP columns using SPARK in parquet tables there is difference how data is inserted.

CDH 5:

HIVE:
If we insert `2019-01-30` to TIMESTAMP column of parquet table and select data from Hive value is `'2019-01-30 00:00:00 0'`

CDH 6:

HIVE:
If we insert `2019-01-30` to TIMESTAMP column of parquet table and select data from HIVE value is `'2019-01-30 04:00:00'`

IMPALA:
If we insert `2019-01-30` to TIMESTAMP column of parquet table and select data from  IMPALA value is '2019-01-30 04:00:00'

Please let me know if there is any spark properties we can use . My primary goal is to match HIVE value in CDH5 vs CDH6 and If possible when we select from IMPALA if should be `2019-01-30 00:00:00'`

Comment: Can you maybe tell what version of Spark you were on then and is on now? Also, as far as I know parquet stores timestamps in UTC, so it could be a presentation layer adjustment.

Comment: We are using Spark 2.3 version

Comment: Maybe you'll find this info useful https://docs.cloudera.com/runtime/7.2.1/developing-spark-applications/topics/spark-timestamp-compatibility-parquet.html. By the way, I believe the default Spark version in CDH6 is 2.4.

Comment: Thanks for sending link. That was or impala . My main issue is date mismatch in HIVE not sure if there is any setting  when compared CDH5 vs CDH6

Answer (score 1):

To skip issues with data type between **Spark** and **Hive** the convention used by **Spark** to write **Parquet** data is configurable.

This is determined by the property `spark.sql.parquet.writeLegacyFormat`. The default value is `false`. If set to `true`, **Spark** will use the same convention as **Hive** for writing the Parquet data.

```scala
val spark = SparkSession
    .builder()
    .appName("MyApp")
    .master("local[*]")
    .config("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions","200") //Change to a more reasonable default number of partitions for our data
    .config("spark.sql.parquet.writeLegacyFormat", true)
```